# Filter model objects, then select a ForeignKey field

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

I have these models in Django:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    ...

class Group(models.Model):
    ...

class Membership(models.Model):
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person, related_name='memberships')
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group, related_name='memberships')
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

I want a Group method that returns the admins, as a list of Person instances.
These are the two solutions I found:

```
class Group(models.Model):
    ...

    @property
    def admins1(self):
        admin_ids = list(self.memberships.filter(is_admin=True).values_list('person', flat=True))
        return list(map(lambda ai: Person.objects.get(pk=ai), admin_ids))

    @property
    def admins2(self):
        admin_memberships = list(self.memberships.filter(is_admin=True))
        return list(map(lambda am: am.person, admin_memberships))
```

Do you have a better idea, e.g. a QuerySet method like `values_list` that keeps Person instances instead of person_ids?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The principle here is always that if you need Person instances, start from Person. Then it becomes simply a matter of following the relationships:

```
Person.objects.filter(membership__is_admin=True, membership__group=self)
```

Also note that Membership is the through table of a many-to-many relationship between Person and Group, so your queries become clearer if you explicitly define it as such:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    ...
    groups = models.ManyToManyField("Group", through="Membership")
```

Now the above query can be:

```
Person.objects.filter(membership__is_admin=True, groups=self)
```